# Show properties of a file right in File Explorer like on Mac

Tags: nautilus, mac, file-properties, application-finder

I'm looking for a plugin for Nautilus, or how do I configure it, or maybe use another file manager, that shows the properties of a file, just like the Mac OS X Finder does (image below). Does anyone have an answer?

Finder on Mac OS X:

[image: Finder - Mac OS X]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after tireless testing, I finally found a file manager capable of giving me the information I needed. And I've used it several times in the past and I don't even remember. The Dolphin!

https://images.pling.com/img/00/00/49/90/47/1339434/732096fd627c0806c131fe6d3d8298afa4876127ae576523d59e24000b91a3f0fdfa.png